# Is there a way to only expand the height of one CSS grid row/column?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm currently rendering a grid of react card components via the map method which I also need to expand. The issue is, when one card expands, the row height obviously changes which then pushes the cards below down the page. This is fine for cards in the same column but it creates an unwanted space between the cards in other non-expanded columns. Is there a way to get around this with CSS-grid?

Unexpanded:
[image: Unexpanded]

Expanded | current effect:
[image: Expanded | current effect]

Expanded | desired effect:
[image: Expanded | desired effect]

This is my current CSS for the grid:

```
layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 30rem);
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  justify-items: center;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
```

Apologies if it's an easy fix, I'm not great with CSS.

Edit -

HTML:

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="card" />
    <div class="card" />
    <div class="card" />
</div>
```

Comment: what is your HTML ?

Comment: Even better if you add a code snippet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What you are looking for is [Masonry](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/) but it´s still experimental
  and doesn´t have a wide support.
- If you are planning to display static content, with fixed sizes, you can adjust size of each grid box proportion using [Mosaic](https://medium.com/@axel/mosaic-layouts-with-css-grid-d13f4e3ed2ae) technique.
- To moderate the issue you can
  center vertically all boxes in their rows by adding   `align-items: center;` to parent element.
- Alternatively, if your layout allows it,
  you may use flexbox with vertical direction, but if width of the
  elements isn´t constant you will encounter the same issue as before:

```css
.content{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 100vh;
    align-content:center;
}

.green{
    height:30vh;
    width: 30vw;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:3px solid black;
}

.box4{
    height:45vh;
}
```

```html
        <div class="content">
            <div class="green box1"></div>
            <div class="green box2"></div>
            <div class="green box3"></div>
            <div class="green box4"></div>
            <div class="green box5"></div>
        </div>
```